# How to read a dynamic csv file?

Tags: python, csv

The function below reads a csv file and appends it to a list, I then use the list in a another function.

```
def get_csv_data(csv_path):
    """
    read test data from csv and return as list

    @type csv_path: string
    @param csv_path: some csv path string
    @return list
    """
    rows = []
    csv_data = open(str(csv_path), "r")
    content = csv.reader(csv_data)

    # skip header line
    next(content, None)

    # add rows to list
    for row in content:
       rows.append(row)

    return rows
```

The issue I am now experiencing is that the csv is dynamically populated in real time by another function. What is the best approach to read the csv up to last current row then reading it again ignoring the previously read rows. To be clear, what i mean is when the function reads the csv e.g up to row 8 then csv is updated with more data, how can the next run start from row 9? Any help and pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could keep track of the lines read so far, and start from there for each call to get_csv_data. S

Comment: @jacoblaw thanks for your suggestion, but how would i implement that?

Comment: Do you have control over the process that updates the file?

Comment: `csv_data.tell()` will return the current position of the file. Remember it, and you can `csv_data.seek()` back to it to start where you left off later.

Comment: @ wwii, yes I do have control over the updating of the file

Answer (score 4):

#### If the file is continuously growing

You need to keep track of the position you have fully read so far,
and the next time the function is called perform a *seek*,
to jump to the location where you left off.

To implement this, you could create a class that will store the seek position,
and a function to read from the last seek position, and update it too.
Or, you could keep the current function, but make it take an additional input for the seek position, and also make it return the new seek position as an additional output.

#### If the file is a stream, open forever and can never be fully read

Instead of reading rows to an array and returning the array,
`yield` the rows as they arrive.

#### If the file gets truncated when new content arrives

This would be a fragile setup,
because you might miss data,
by not reading it before it gets truncated.
So this probably won't deserve serious thought.